# Has the Weierstass transform been used to give Hermite series representations of the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, riemann-zeta-function, hermite-polynomials

The inverse of the [Weierstrass transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform)
 expands a function as a series of Hermite polynomials $H_{n}$. There are several ways to invert the Weierstrass transform which led me to the following expansions:

1. Along the critical line

   > > $\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+ix\right)=\sum \limits^{\infty}_{m=0}\left[\sum \limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{1/2+\ln (n)/4}}\Bigl(\dfrac{-i\ln n}{2}\Bigr)^{m}\right]\dfrac{H_{m}\left(x\right)}{m!}\text{.}$
2. Hasse's representation yields

   > > $\zeta\left(z\right)\left(1-2^{1-z}\right)=\sum \limits^{\infty}_{m=0}\left[\sum \limits^{\infty}_{n=0}  \sum \limits^{n}_{k=0}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k} \ln^m\left(k+1\right) }{2^{n+1}}\binom{n}{k}e^{\ln^2(k+1)  /4}\right]\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{m}H_{m}\left(z\right)}{2^{m}m!}\text{.}$
3. The Laurent series yields

   > > $\zeta\left(z+1\right)-\frac{1}{z}=\sum \limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\dfrac{1}{2^nn!}\left[\sum \limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{\gamma_{n+2k}}{2^{2k+1}k!}\right]H_{n}\left(z\right)$
   > >
   > > > where the $\gamma_{n}$ are the Stieltjes constants.

Et cetera. The calculations were all formal, and I've mostly ignored convergence, assuming this territory is well-trod. Has this been explored, or is there some flaw in this approach?

Also, is there some better way to find a Hermite expansion of $\zeta$?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think he means to ask if these are actually correct, and what other similar expansions (in terms of Hermite polynomials) are there which are connected to $\zeta$.  

Comment: Newly edited for clarification.

Comment: What don't you write the formal manipulations that lead to the 1st formula ?